# Show $(\mathbb{R},0,+,-)$ has infinitely many automorphisms

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, model-theory

Show $(\mathbb{R},0,+,-)$ has infinitely many automorphisms :

My idea is that if $\phi:(\mathbb{R},0,+,-) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},0,+,-)$ is an automorphism. Then since here we don't have the order relation. For any $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, $(x_1,x_2 ) \rightarrow (y_1, y_2)$ will be an automorphism. In another words, any we can always map an open interval to another open interval to have automorphism.

Could someone let me know if my thinking is correct?

If not, could you let me know what went wrong, and how should I fix it?

Any hints or ideas will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I assume "automorphism" means that it preserves the given operations... $\phi(0)=0$, $\phi(x+y) = \phi(x)+\phi(y)$, $\phi(-y) = -\phi(y)$.  Can you think of such functions?  Infinitely many of them?

Comment: Other than the identity function, we can just multiply any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ by any constant. Would that work?

Comment: Correct.  You get one map $x \mapsto ax$ for each multiplier $a$.  But which of these are bijective?

Comment: $a$ has to be prime, is that right?

Comment: Prime? no.  $x \mapsto \sqrt{2}\;x$ will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you propose in the comments is correct: For any non-zero $r\in \mathbb{R}$, the function $x\mapsto rx$ is an automorphism of $(\mathbb{R},0,+,-)$. I'll leave it to you to check the details.

On the other hand, what you've written doesn't make any sense to me. You say "$(x_1,x_2)\to (y_1,y_2)$ will be an automorphism". What function $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ do you have in mind here? It's not true that any open interval can be  mapped to any other open interval by an automorphism. For example, $(-1,1)$ can't be mapped to $(1,2)$, since the first interval contains $0$, the second does not contain $0$, and any automorphism maps $0$ to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* $\mathbb R$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation

Comment: But this result is not needed for the question.

Comment: Expanding on @GEdgar's comment, it's not just overkill - it actually proves a *weaker* result. $\mathsf{ZF}$ (= set theory without choice) does **not** prove that $\mathbb{R}$ has a basis as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, and indeed "Every vector space has a basis" is equivalent to the full axiom of choice. The "scaling" solution is not only simpler, it also doesn't need any set-theoretic hypotheses.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, indeed. Thanks.